# How to turn a Timestamp string into DateTime format in Excel?

Tags: excel, string, datetime, timestamp

I have a string such as `10/21/19 5:45:40 AM +00:00` in a CSV and would like to create a pivot table to see how many times the door has been opened per hour.

This only works when Excel understands the `Timestamp` string as a timestamp.

I've tried `=DATEVALUE()` and formatting but Excel still can't make sense of the string.

I'm in UK locale, so dd/mm/yyyy.

What's the best way to get this to work? Thanks!

[image: Excel Time Series]

Comment: If you import your CSV with a custom import, you can set the type of each column.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `+00:00` part of the string:

```
=--(LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-6))
```

Then format the cell as desired like : `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`

[image]

---

If your local date is `dd/mm/yyyy` use this:

```
=DATE(20&TRIM(MID(A2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","|",2))+1,2)),SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,FIND("/",A2)+1,2),"/",""),LEFT(A2,FIND("/",A2)-1))+MID(LEFT(A2,FIND("+",A2)-2),FIND(" ",A2)+1,99)
```

And format as desired.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried variations of this. But my suspicion is because it is an AM/PM format this won't work? Also, the first hour is sometimes 1 digit, sometimes 2, which doesn't allow me to do string manipulation counting characters. Or am I missing anything?

Comment: did you try it?  What is the output of only the `=LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-6)` part?  AM/PM should not matter.

Comment: I get 10/21/19 5:45 for row 2 for example. But I don't know if that's AM or PM. Because further down, when it's 1PM it still says 1 and not 13.

Comment: then change the format to `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM`

Comment: I've tried `mm/dd/yy h:mm:ss am/pm`, `mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss am/pm`,`mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM`, `mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss AM/PM`, `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss am/pm` and all its variations without success. There must be something simple or trivial I must be missing?

Comment: If you format it as General does it change to a number with decimal places?  If not post the exact formula you used.

Comment: No, it doesn't change to a number. I don't use a formula, the plain text is `10/21/19 5:45:40 AM` now (after I've removed the +00:00 manually) and if I try to use `=DATEVALUE(A2)` on it, it gives me `#VALUE` even if I put the format on all of the above mentioned.

Comment: You need to use my formula. on the original data in a different column, it removes the `+00:00` part and forces it to a date:time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201422/discussion-between-chrisb-and-scott-craner).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using **Text to Columns** function under the `Data` tab.

I used the following data for demonstration:

```
| Timestamp                   | Sensor    | Action |
|-----------------------------|-----------|--------|
| 10/21/19 5:45:40 AM +00:00  | Shop Door | Open   |
| 10/22/19 9:37:12 AM +00:00  | Shop Door | Open   |
| 10/22/19 9:38:15 AM +00:00  | Shop Door | Open   |
| 10/22/19 9:39:23 AM +00:00  | Shop Door | Open   |
| 10/22/19 9:40:27 AM +00:00  | Shop Door | Open   |
| 10/22/19 9:41:28 AM +00:00  | Shop Door | Open   |
| 10/22/19 9:42:30 AM +00:00  | Shop Door | Open   |
| 10/22/19 9:43:32 AM +00:00  | Shop Door | Open   |
| 10/22/19 9:44:35 AM +00:00  | Shop Door | Open   |
| 10/22/19 9:45:36 AM +00:00  | Shop Door | Open   |
| 10/22/19 9:48:38 AM +00:00  | Shop Door | Open   |
| 10/22/19 9:47:41 AM +00:00  | Shop Door | Open   |
| 10/22/19 9:48:41 AM +00:00  | Shop Door | Open   |
| 10/22/19 9:49:42 AM +00:00  | Shop Door | Open   |
| 10/22/19 9:53:11 AM +00:00  | Shop Door | Open   |
| 10/22/19 10:07:30 AM +00:00 | Shop Door | Open   |
| 10/22/19 10:16:32 AM +00:00 | Shop Door | Open   |
| 10/22/19 10:22:27 AM +00:00 | Shop Door | Open   |
| 10/22/19 10:23:27 AM +00:00 | Shop Door | Open   |
| 10/22/19 10:24:29 AM +00:00 | Shop Door | Open   |
| 10/22/19 10:25:58 AM +00:00 | Shop Door | Open   |
| 10/22/19 10:27:03 AM +00:00 | Shop Door | Open   |
| 10/22/19 10:28:09 AM +00:00 | Shop Door | Open   |
| 10/22/19 10:29:15 AM +00:00 | Shop Door | Open   |
| 10/22/19 10:30:20 AM +00:00 | Shop Door | Open   |
```

Steps are:

1. Highlight `Column A` which is the *Timestamp* column;
2. Click **Text to Columns** button under the `Data` tab;
3. Select **Fixed Width**, click next;
4. Left click somewhere between the time and `+00:00` to insert a column break, click next;

[image: Insert Col Break]

5. Highlight the first column which is date, and set the format to `MDY` under `Date`, leave the format of the other two columns as default, click Finish;

[image: MDY]

6. It is **OK** to overwrite the data in Column B and C given that they are irrelevant in structuring the pivot table;
7. Highlight the new table (including headers) and insert a pivot table, put the `Timestamp` and `Sensor` under **Rows** filed, and put `Action` under the **Values** field, then you should have something like the following:

[image: Pivot Table]

Here is the Fields setting:

[image: Fields]

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)